# Retrofit2 async task error even when using enqueue

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit2, networkonmainthread

so i'm getting a crash on this app i'm building  every-time i try to upload a photo to the server. heres the error message

```
 android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:214)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:212)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)
    at com.quantamfig.docuflow.SubmitActivity.postValuesRetro(SubmitActivity.java:274)
    at com.quantamfig.docuflow.SubmitActivity$2.onClick(SubmitActivity.java:206)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

as you can see, im getting a NetworkonMainThreadExeption error () even though im running the code asynchronously using enqueue.Please someone help me figure this out

Answer (score 0):

so the problem was, i was trying to log a call Object method(callObj.execute) outside the enqeue and therefore on the main thread. i took it out and it worked.